# how to continue http until result is found

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a http call which when starts calling first few seconds is error 404 until the result is coming to database:

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`).subscribe(s=>{
 console.log(s);
 },error=>(error));
```

what i thought is to put it inside while

```
        shouldCall=true;
        while(shouldCall){
         this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`).subscribe(s=>{
         console.log(s);
         shouldCall=false;
         },error=>(error));}
```

the problem is the browser  crashes with this approach, any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat ajax call until success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583302/how-to-repeat-ajax-call-until-success)

Comment: Did you try debugging? What happens if you put a log in the while loop but outside of the Observable? Hint: this is async code, there's no wait between each request..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i repeat an ajax request until a condition is met with RxJS Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400594/how-do-i-repeat-an-ajax-request-until-a-condition-is-met-with-rxjs-observable)

Comment: @GaëlJ should i write my httpcall inside flatmap?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `retry` operator which will retry the stream until success

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
.pipe(retry())
subscribe(s=>{
 console.log(s);
 },error=>(error));
```

You can also add a param to specify max number of retry e.g `retry(5)`

Comment: how can i say every 5 seconds rettry?

Comment: you can add `delay(5000)` operator before `retry`.